# Scroll only showing part of the element

Tags: html, css

so am trying to make a table have a fixed size and horizontally scrollable, and I added
`overflow-x: auto;`, but for some reason it only scrolling part of the table while the start of the table is outside of the screen, I am unable to show the code so here is a sample to make it clearer[image]

the green part can be scrolled normally but the scrollbar end it the red part, when I zoom out or add margin it appears, but that is not really a solution.
The table is inside a flex container if that matters, but does not have anything applied on it.
thanks

Comment: why you cant post code?
it is difficult to help without knowing your setup (html, css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `overflow-x: scroll;` instead of `overflow-x: auto;`

Comment: the to has allready a scrollbar, but it is not scrolling the full table, as i understanded, so `overflow-x: scroll;` will only force the scrollbar to be there even when he dont need it

Answer (score 0):

So, I will try to guess your code as you could not share with some assumption and provides some steps may help:

- try to get your table outside and test if the issue still there!! if yes your issue is mainly with your table style
- if no, try to change the flow of FLEX container to be column and check if fixed.
- if still try to add min to div containing your table inside the flex
  container

otherwise, you should provide a small sample of your code to sort out the issue more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

- remove `justify-content: center` on your div if you have one.
  i was having the same problem ,then i found out that having `justify-content: center` on the div was the one causing the issue.